# How can i run a command in Powershell when setting variables?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run the following in powershell:

```
   $str1="c:\windows\system32\
   $str2 = "notepad.exe"
   $str3 = $str1$str2
   &$str3
```

It doesnt recognize $str3. I want to set the variable and then run the command. I need $str2 as this is set via an app and i dont know what it may be , but it will always be a .exe .How can i get this to run ?

Comment: Use proper *string concatenation*. Either quote the 2 variables so it can join them as one: `$str3 = "$str1$str2"`, or use `+` operator to join them together: `$str3 = $str1 + $str2`. You can use other methods but these are the most common

Comment: Ok , but then how can i run the command in the powershell window after setting. So i will set them and the run them ?

Comment: you're doing it already with `& $str3`.

Comment: Now what if my pathe was something like C:\Program Files\My App , how can i put that in a string , is it double quotes ?

Comment: Would it hurt you when you just tried? Your questions are quite basic. You may use your prefered internet search engine to look for answers. That will be even faster than waiting here for answers. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: For safety measures use `Join-Path` : `Join-Path -Path $str1 -ChildPath $str2`

Comment: Thankyou @Abraham Zinala   you input as been very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you are missing the quote at the end of line one and when you join two variables together you have to either use + to concatenate them or put them in quotes:

```
$str1 + $str2
```

or

```
"$str1$str2"
```

But when joining two variables with path and/or filenames you want to use Join-Path. This way the slash at the end of the path does not cause issues if it happens to be missing:

```
$str1 = "c:\windows\system32\"
$str2 = "notepad.exe"
$str3 = Join-Path $str1 $str2
& $str3
```

The above will work correctly even if $str1 is missing the slash at the end.